# Как избавиться от утечки памяти

Tags: c++, сегментация

Есть код, при рантайме выдает ошибку сегментации:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class StudentList
{
private:
    class Student
    {
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
        double height;

    public:
        Student *next;
        explicit Student(string n,int a,double h):
        name(n),
        age(a),
        height(h)
        {}

        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }
        double getHeight()
        {
            return height;
        }
        ~Student()
        {}
    };

    Student *temp;
public:
    explicit StudentList()
    {
        temp=NULL;
    }

    ~StudentList()
    {

    }

    void list()
    {
        Student* student=temp;
        while(student)
        {
            cout<<temp->getName()<<"\t"<<temp->getAge()<<"\t"<<temp->getHeight()<<"\n";
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        //delete student;
    }

    void insertValue(string name,int age,double height)
    {
        Student *student=new Student(name,age,height);
        student->next=temp;
        temp=student;
    }
};


int main()
{
  StudentList ls;
  ls.insertValue("Falcao",45,1.87);
  ls.insertValue("Jacob",97,3.87);
  ls.list();
}
```

проблема в функии лист..

Comment: Почитайте о том как должен выглядеть [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

У Вас переменная student в методе list проверяется в цикле, но не меняется. Вместо неё меняется поле temp. По идее, нужно заменить `temp=temp->next;` на что-то вроде `student=student->next;`. Это то, что сразу бросается в глаза. А чтобы не было именно утечки памяти (seg fault - это не утечка, это попытка обращения к памяти, к которой у программы нет доступа), нужно деструктор для класса StudentList написать. Чтобы он по очереди удалял всех студентов.